# Submit first form while pressing the submit button in 3rd form

Tags: html, forms

I have a checkout form (#form1) with client details fields & submit button. The first checkout form closes .
A new form is opened then closed(i have info with updating product qty here).

Next (after the second form is closed) below I need to put a submit button which will submit the first form (the one with client details). So the question is how can I make form #3 submit form #1 without js?

Comment: Why without js, jus askin.

Comment: The fact that the form "closes" and another "opens" suggests you are already using JavaScript. That doesn't sound possible or reasonable to do without JavaScript.

Comment: Apparently its not possible without JS I guess. Because HTML itself isn't that much powerful yet.

Comment: @SecondRikudo I have about 3 forms on the page and want to add a new one to submit one of already availble forms. No js is used for submiting a form ;)

Comment: @WhirlMind Some time people have js turned off and it would be annoying if there will be a submit button and it wont submit the form ;)

Comment: @UsmanTahir Seems like with regret I need to agree with you... Will post my solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading the HTML manual and thanks to a guy (nick moo-_-) on IRC #html5 channel who gave me a tip I found the solution.

In case you want to submit a form outside the form tags you may use the button tag. The button tag is valid even if it's not closed in  tags.

tag can have an attribute **"form"**. By using this attribute you can taget any form on the page you want and by using the attribute **[type="submit"]** you can submit the required form.

The solution:

```
<button type="submit" form="Form-Id-To-Submit">Submit the form</button>
```

No need for applause. Thank U :)